# Image capture "import error (-50)" images import fine, but won't delete from phone?

Tags: iphone, photos, image-capture

My iPhone 5 recently broke, so I got an iPhone 5s. I restored from a backup using iTunes, and configured any remaining settings fine.

Usually to take images from my phone's camera I plug the phone into the computer and use Image Capture, then drag the images from Image Capture to the file I want. I have the "delete after import" setting selected so that the images are removed from my phone after import to save space.

Now when I try this with the new phone it works fine on importing the photos, but I get an error (see attached screenshot) and the images don't auto delete from my phone.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

---

**UPDATE - Laptop & Phone Spec**

My computer - Mid 2012 MBP 15" running osx 10.9.5

My iPhone - 5s running iOS 8.3

[image: screenshot of image capture]

Comment: Not the same issue but may be related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/971/38539

Comment: Which are the versions of OS X and iOS we are talking about?

Comment: @juandesant good point, its OSX 10.9.5 and IOS 8.3, ive updated this in the question also

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this is now solved on my iPhone. I'm not 100% sure how I did it but the 2 notable things I did very recently were:

1. rename the iPhone from "iphone(3)" to "Sam's iPhone"
2. turned off iCloud on the iPhone then turned in back on

Not sure which one solved it; would be good if any one who has this issue does the same and report back to be able to clarify.

Comment: I recently helped a family member with this very issue, turning off iCloud did the trick. I never renamed the iPhone so I'd say it's probably iCloud.

Answer (score -1):

restart computer. it may too much applications running in the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions